# Given a string, determine whether any permutation of it is a palindrome

Tags: python, string, palindrome

I am trying to determine that whether any string is palindrome or not. For example, carrace should return true, since it can be rearranged to form racecar, which is a palindrome. daily should return false since there's no rearrangement that can form a palindrome.
How can I solve this ?

**Code:**

```
string = 'racecar'
if string[::-1] == string:
    print('palindrome')
```

Above code is working for single  string , not for permutations

Comment: You have added the `python` tag, but you have added no code to your question.

Comment: carrace is not a palindrome

Comment: Ok, I see you have added some code. What were you thinking you could do about rearranging the letters?

Comment: yes and then checking ..

Comment: I see your code performs a check already. What were you thinking you could do about rearranging the letters?

Comment: yes and then check for each permutations

Comment: What *code* were you thinking about that could rearrange the letters?

Comment: That is what I am asking

Comment: But you haven't written any code that rearranges letters. We can't help you with code you haven't written.

Comment: not arranging the letters is kinda the point of this exercise.

Comment: sure , i will take care of it next time

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A string can be permuted to a palindrome **if and only if** there is at most **one character that occurs an odd number of times**.

```
from collections import Counter

def permute_palindrome(s):
    return sum(1 for i in Counter(s).values() if i%2) <= 1

assert permute_palindrome('carrace')
assert not permute_palindrome('daily')
```

**Detailed explanation:**

**Any palindrome has at most one character that occurs and odd number of times:**
Consider any palindrome `aabbcccbbaa`
Note that by the definition of a palindrome any character on the left side is matched on the right side, so it forms a pair with this character.  Counting characters in pairs will always lead to an even number (any multiple of 2 is an even number).  The only exception to this is the middle character of an odd length string, this character is 'paired' with itself.  So there is at most one character occuring an odd length number of times.

**Any string that has at most one character occuring an odd number of times can be permuted to a palindrome:**
We show a construction of a palindrome p in the following way.  If there is a character occuring an odd number of times, add this to p.  For any character occuring an even number of times, split this into two and add one part to the beginning of p and one part to the end of p.  This results in a palindrome.

ex:  aabbbbccd
p = d
p = ada
p = bbadabb
p = cbbadabbc

Comment: Nice logic. I just mapped over all permutations.

Comment: I cannot understand the logic, perhaps I am interpreting wrong. Can you please explain it a little?

Comment: @Sujay added some more text, did it help?

Comment: @ChristianSloper Yes! So +1

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import permutations

def palindrome(s: str) -> bool:
    return ''.join(reversed(s)) == s

def permutated_palindrome(s: str) ->:
    return any(map(palindrome,
               map(''.join, permutations(s))
               ))
```

Comment: it is not for permutations too !

Comment: Adjusted for permutations

Comment: While fine for short s, this will be very, very slow as soon as s grows about 15 or so.

Comment: @ChristianSloper, Yeah, your BigO is a lot nicer ;) People, his is linear, use his answer and put the reasoning in a comment, because to understand what the code does, you need it.  (Or it might even be constant time, I don't know how Counter and sum are implemented.)

Comment: @ChrisWesseling I have added more text to explain my idea, The running time is O(n) (Counter need to see the entire string to count it).

Answer (score 0):

**Java concise version**

```
boolean isPermutationPalindrome(String s){
    Set<Character> charSet = new HashSet<>();
    for ( char c : s.toCharArray() ) {
        if (!charSet.contains(c))
            charSet.add(c);
        else
            charSet.remove(c);
    }
    return charSet.size() <= 1;
}
```